# Is it possible to count in MSBuild?

Tags: .net, msbuild

All I'm doing is trying to keep track of the number of times a certain target gets called. Is it possible to do this using msbuild?

EDIT:

I tried doing something like this:

```
<Message Text ="The sum of $(NumberOne) and $(NumberTwo) is $([MsBuild]::Add($(NumberOne),$(NumberTwo))"/>
```

but that didn't work either. My output was 
 The sum of 2 and 3 is $([MsBuild]::Add($(NumberOne),$(NumberTwo))

As for the suggestion to use an Item: I guess I could use some more information. I did some reading on Items, but don't see how they can be used as integers. It looks as thought they're for file collections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And your example work fine, you just have mistake in class name: it should be  **[MSBuild]**, not **[MsBuild]**

```
<Message Text ="The sum of $(NumberOne) and $(NumberTwo) is $([MSBuild]::Add($(NumberOne), $(NumberTwo)))">
```

Comment: Wow. I feel silly. Thanks. I don't have access to a computer with msbuild on it right now, but I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is.  Create an item and then use Math.Add to increment it:

```
<Math.Add Numbers="$(ITEM);1">
    <Output TaskParameter="Result" PropertyName="ITEM"/>
</Math.Add>
```

Comment: I don't think I fully understand the answer, after all. Should I create an ItemGroup containing this Item? What do I assign to the Item's required Include field?

Comment: Looks like schulz mean that you should use Math.Add task from Msbuild Community Extension.